# touchesBegan not working swift 4

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, swift4

I created a seperate UIView class to detect the user touch.

```
class SelectionView: UIView {
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesBegan")
     }

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesMoved")
     }

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesEnded")
     }
}
```

then I just took a view and assign SelectionView class to it.

But when i touches or moving on view none of the methods called

I checked many of the previous related questions. But not able to resolve the issue

I checkd:- 
- user interection is enabled for the view
- view is on the top

Comment: It works to me, try to provide more info

Comment: Make sure `UIView` `userInteraction` is enable.

Comment: did you check the `userInteraction ` of SelectionView's super view, too?

Comment: IS it embed in a scrollview? Maybe that captures your touch events

Comment: Where you are using this view?